# Bleutooth headphones Galaxy Buds TouchPad types characters in Remote Desktop (RDP)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, bluetooth, headphones

I use Galaxy Buds (bleutooth headphones) on my Laptop. On the Buds there is a touchpad that can be used to control my phone (if they are connected to the phone).

From my Laptop i use a remote desktop connection to my work PC (a virtual machine). Now if I touch the buds, a character is typed into the VM (single touch is a 'g', double touch a 'p' and tripple a 'q'.

When I do this on my laptop, nothing happens.

In my Remove Desktop configuration, under 'local devices and resources', I have only 'shared' the C-drive of my laptop. (no priters, clipboard, etc.).

How is this possible? And how can I stop this?